# How to convert nan to NULL in database table using Pandas

Tags: python, django, pandas

In my CSV some columns are empty but when I'm inserting CSV data so in the place of the empty column nun is coming but I want NULL in the table

```
file = request.FILES['csvfile']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['company’])
if not df.loc[i]['company'] == 'NaN':
    company = df.loc[i]['company']
else:
    company = None 
Company.objects.update_or_create(company_name=company)
```

I want Null in the database table when the column is empty But when I'm using the above code that giving me nun in the place of the empty column

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. The below worked for me:

df.astype(object).replace(np.nan, None)

Comment: Hi Jeff - does this answer your question? If so, please mark as such

Answer (score 2):

I fixed a similar issue by modifying `pd.read_csv()`. I added the following arguments:

`keep_default_na=False, na_values=None`